# IF/ELSE Condition in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do an IF/ELSE statement for PLSQL but I am not sure if I am doing it the right way as it is always having an error: Missing right parenthesis on **IF (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 6, 2)) != TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 1, 2))) THEN**
but the parenthesis seems balance to me.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
IF (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 6, 2)) != TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 1, 2))) THEN
  SELECT ID, DATE, ATTR_VALUE, (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 6, 4))-TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 1, 4))-48) DIFF
ELSE
  SELECT ID, DATE, ATTR_VALUE, (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 6, 4))-TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 1, 4))) DIFF
END IF
FROM Table A
ORDER BY TIME
)
WHERE DIFF>26
```

Please kindly assist me on this issue.

Comment: Your example is plain SQL, there is no PL/SQL (stored procedures) involved

Comment: The if statement is only in pl/sql you need to use the case or decode statements as others have suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use a `CASE` statement to get the result:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT ID, 
    DATE, 
    ATTR_VALUE,
    CASE 
      WHEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 6, 2)) != TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 1, 2))
      THEN (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 6, 4))-TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 1, 4))-48)
      ELSE (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 6, 4))-TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 1, 4)))
    END DIFF
  FROM Table A
  ORDER BY TIME
)
WHERE DIFF>26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query to something on the lines as shown below,

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ID,
               DATE,
               ATTR_VALUE,
               decode(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 6, 2)),
                      TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 1, 2)),
                      TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 6, 4)) -
                      TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 1, 4)),
                      TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 6, 4)) -
                      TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ATTR_VALUE, 1, 4))) DIFF
          FROM A)
 WHERE diff > 26
```